# Number $ e $ formula significance

Tags: exponential-function

Number $ e $ was formed using Compound interest formula $ ( 1 + \frac 1 n ) ^ n $. when $ n $ becomes so large $ e $ will approach constant $ 2.7182818 $. In the same way if we alter formula to be $ ( 1 + \frac 2 n ) ^ n $ then also it approach a irrational constant $ 7.389041 $. This is true with any number. So, what was significance about using $ 1 $ and naming it as $ e $.

Comment: That irrational constant $7.3890...$ is $e^2$. In general $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (1+x/n)^{1/n}=e^x$$ Isn't that cool? How could you say that without naming $e$?

Comment: "e will approach constant". NO. $e$ *is* a constant.

Comment: @Crostul Typo in the exponent?

Answer (score 1):

Just notice that:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+\frac{a}{n})^n = e^a$$

Comment: It should be $n\to\infty$